# Syntax error - Android application attempting to tweet to Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm new to programming so I was trying to make an Android application which could post tweets on Twitter. I found a tutorial at http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/04/using-twitter4j-to-tweet-in-android.html using Twitter4J, specifically, *twitter4j-core-android-2.2.5.jar*.

I get a syntax error for the last line in the code, which is commented out below, stating "**Unhandled exception type TwitterException.**"

I thought I solved the problem using a try catch but it didn't work and gave me a run-time error when I tested it on a real device. Can anyone provide a solution or insight to whether this implementation would work?

```
try{
    twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
    } catch(TwitterException e){
    }



package com.XXXX.tweet;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;

public class tweet extends Activity {
    private static final String oauth_token = "XXXX";
    private static final String oauth_token_secret = "XXXX";
    private final static String consumer_token = "XXXX";
    private final static String consumer_secret = "XXXX";

String tweet = "This is a test Tweet.";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret);
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumer_token, consumer_secret);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

        //twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
    }
};
```

Comment: Unhandled exception type TwitterException

Comment: there should be an exception message or the location of exact line that generate exception